# Does this PHP image upload code has any secure bugs(Image files on LNMP server had been malicious replaced)?

Tags: php, linux, upload, nginx, debian

I just found out that thousands of original image files on my Debian Server had been replaced by thumbnail image files.
And I'm sure that I haven't done this operation by myself.
So there must be some hacker entered my server and course the damage.
But when I check the last login history during the files been replaced,there is no suspicious logins.
So I think there might be some secure problem with my PHP code.
Below is my PHP image upload code:

```
function upload() {
    $sql = "SELECT photocount FROM user WHERE id={$_SESSION['id']}";
    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql); 
        $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        if($user->photocount<9){
            $filename = explode(".",$_FILES['upload_file']['name']);
            $ext = end($filename);
            $ctime = time();
            $filename = $ctime.$_SESSION['id'].".".$ext;
            header('content-type:text/html charset:utf-8');
            if(!file_exists($_FILES['upload_file']['name'])) move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'],"uploads/" .$filename);
            $resizeimage = new resizeimage("uploads/".$filename, "160", "160", "1","uploads/small/".$filename);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO photo (uid,thumbnail,original) VALUES('{$_SESSION['id']}','http://chongai.co/m/uploads/small/{$filename}', 'http://chongai.co/m/uploads/{$filename}')";
            $sqll = "UPDATE user SET photocount=photocount+1 WHERE id={$_SESSION['id']}";
            try {
                $stmt = $db->query($sql); 
                $stmt = $db->query($sqll); 
                $sql = "SELECT id FROM photo WHERE thumbnail='http://chongai.co/m/uploads/small/{$filename}'";          
                $stmt = $db->query($sql); 
                $img = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $db = null;     
                echo '{"status": ' . json_encode("Upload Success") . ',"file": ' . json_encode("http://chongai.co/m/uploads/small/{$filename}") . ',"id": ' . json_encode($img->id) . '}';
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
            }           
        }else{
            echo '{"status": ' . json_encode("You can only upload 8 photos") . '}';
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
}
```

BTW: My web server was nginx.

Any help would be greatful!
ths!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are security bugs. The upload filename is controlled by the user:

```
$filename = explode(".",$_FILES['upload_file']['name']);
$ext = end($filename);
```

- the filename doesn't necessarily have to contain a dot, `$ext` will be the whole filename
- everyting after the last dot will end up in `$ext`

In both cases `$ext` can be freely controlled by an attacker, and seen that you later use it in your sql query without sanitation, you have a serious sql injection vulnerability.

You shouldn't build sql queries by concatenating strings. You're using PDO, so do yourself a favor and use [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), it will save you a lot of trouble.

---

edit:

Another vulnerability may be that your script allows you to upload any file type, so if you didn't disable execution of php for your upload directory, anyone could upload a php file which would then be executed on the server.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem,but the ext and SQL thing can't cause image files being moved and replaced,can they?

Comment: No, but it would allow to delete the database or insert arbitrary data. I have no idea what `new resizeimage(...)` does, so I can't say if it's secure or not.

Comment: Thanks,I've add a statement before upload the file:`if($ext!="jpg"&&$ext!="png"&&$ext!="gif"&&$ext!="jpeg")` and use `$db->prepare($sql)` before execute.